# Bitbucket REST API appears to be stripping off final line endings

Tags: git, newline, bitbucket-api

I have versioned in Git the following text file `dummy.txt`:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Mary had a little lamb whose fleece was white as snow.
(no content, just a newline here at the end)
```

When making the following API call:

```
https://stash.domain.com:8443/rest/api/1.0/projects/some_project/dummy.txt
```

I receive back the following content:

```
{
    "lines" : [
        {"text":"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."},
        {"text":"Mary had a little lamb whose fleece was white as snow."}
    ],
    "start":0,
    "size":2,
    "isLastPage":true
}
```

In other words, the newline at the end of the original text file has disappeared.  I am at a loss to explain this.  Perhaps my local Git is stripping the newline, or perhaps Bitbucket has been configured to do this.  Yet, doing a `git fetch` does not bring in a version of the text file with the final line ending removed.  I should note that one trailing newline is always removed.  For example, if the source file has 5 newlines at the end, then the API will return 4 back.

As it turns out, for what we plan to do with the Bitbucket this is probably not an issue, but I was hoping someone could shed light on what is happening here.